# Having different account on same MacBook for development and personal use?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

I have two MacBook's which i are for personal use. I have a personal Apple ID which i use on all my Devices. Now i want to start developing on these MacBook also and i read on the net, that it is preferred having the Development Account, which is used for enrolling the Individual Developer Program, separated from the Personal Account. But before i do this i want to understand how this will affect the work on my MacBook's. Do i have to login with this other account when i want to develop and login with the personal account when i just want to do private things?

Comment: You can switch between accounts using "Fast User Switching". There's no harm in creating another account and trying it out an deleting it if you don't like it. Here's the Apple Doc: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/switch-quickly-between-users-mchlp2439/mac